# How to select an appropriate service implementation?

Tags: java, osgi

I've created a service with multiple implementations, like so:

```
@ProviderType
public interface MyService {
    public void printMessage();
}

@Component
public class Foo implements MyService {
    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

@Component
public class Bar implements MyService {
    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
}
```

The real implementations are obviously a bit more complex (I can't just make a single implementation where `printMessage` takes an argument!). The consumers of the service need to be able to select an appropriate implementation based on a property - for simplicity, we can assume I'm using the name of the implementation.

The factory method used by the existing non-OSGi implementation is something like this:

```
public MyService getService(String property) {
    switch (property) {
        case "ham":
            return new Foo();
        case "spam":
            return new Bar();
    }
}
```

The real implementation is, again, more complicated (it's based on a substring match of the `property` parameter). The simplest approach (for me) to convert this to OSGi would be to make this factory method into a static method of `MyService`, returning only the necessary filter string, and to make consumers take care of the fiddly bits with getting a BundleContext, then getting and ungetting the service:

```
public class MyConsumer {
    private BundleContext context;

    @Activate
    public void activate(BundleContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        Collection<ServiceReference<MyService>> refs = context.getServiceReferences(MyService.class, MyService.getService("ham"));
        ServiceReference<MyService> service = refs.iterator().next();
        context.getService(service).printMessage();
        context.ungetService(service);
    }
```

**Is there a better way to create a "factory" that returns "services", but doesn't require that the consumers deal with BundleContexts etc.?**

I've found a couple approaches that won't *quite* work:

- `@Reference(target = "ham")` (I know that syntax is wrong) allows me to select an implementation based on a property, but only at compile-time.
- A `ServiceFactory` allows different bundles to get different instances of the service, but not to specify implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a service is that the consumer should NOT select because that makes the consumers very un-reusable. It generally makes brittle systems if you move that control into the consumer. The consumer should use whatever is registered.

One anti-pattern is that you try to hide the implementation of the service but then needing a specific implementation in your consumer. If this is your use cases, your implementation is public and just make it its own service type. It could still register as the common MyService type as well of course, you can register under multiple types.

If you have an outside selection criteria for which one to use, e.g. a printer and you want the user to decide, then you just get all and show them to the user. Using the service id you can use the right one.

If you need to configure which service should be used then you should use the `@Reference(target="(selection.criterium=foo)")`. You can override this selection with Configuration Admin. This is explained in [targets](http://enroute.osgi.org/doc/217-ds.html#targets-or-how-to-wire-services). You basically set a property with the name of the reference followed by `.target` to the required filter.

Comment: The actual use case is for an integration test tool; the service implementations I'm asking about test correctness for different file types. The non-OSGi version allows tests to write arbitrary output files and selects the appropriate service implementation with a factory. If we convert the tests themselves to services implementing ServiceFactory, then we can create new test instances with Config Admin and use a target to define their output type (pretty sure we've got that info available). Thanks

Comment: So in that case you should let the service that knows the type make the decision. In such a case the consumer should iterate over all services and ask the service if it can handle the file type. If so, it should do the verification. If you're not extremely careful, you'll find that the consumer knows all possible file types and it becomes a hotspot because every time you add a new file type you need to update it.